System.InvalidOperationException: Web service method name is not valid
When I use POSTMAN to test a webservice with a request in XML I always receive that error message:
System.InvalidOperationException: The method name of the SplitValues ​​web service is not valid. at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.Initialize() at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)
The code used is as follows:
<WebMethod(Description:="Divide dois valores e retorna o resultado.")>
Public Function DividirValores(request As DivisaoRequest) As DivisaoResponse
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/xml"
    Dim response As New DivisaoResponse()
    Try
        'Validação
        If request.Valor2 = 0 Then
            Throw New DivideByZeroException("Não é possível dividir por zero.")
        End If

        ' Cálculo
          response.Resultado = request.Valor1 / request.Valor2
          response.Mensagem = String.Empty

    Catch ex As Exception
        ' Erro
        response.Resultado = Nothing
        response.Mensagem = ex.MessageEnd 
    Try
    Return response
End Function

I hope someone can help me resolve this issue...

Keep in mind your translation. SplitValues is not the name of the method, but your error message suggests that's your problem. Be clear. Maybe we need more information, too.
